# Cordova Browser

Tags: css, cordova

I just started using Cordova for my apps. I have some CSS3 features I want to implement and I want to know : Does Cordova have its own browser that runs the apps or does it use the device's browser ?

Comment: You might find this interesting: http://agiliq.com/blog/2012/09/dissecting-phonegaps-architecture/

Comment: Thanks @balzafin, it is an excellent description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Cordova uses a generic WebView, which depends on the plateforme it runs on.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the webview of the device its running on. So, if you want to code any html,html5,css,css3,javascript or jquery its like coding for safari web browser if you are developing for iphone and coding for chrome or android phone browser if you are developing for the android platform.

Comment: Ummmm... you basically just repeated Mehdiway's answer, but just a few extra words.